# FindMaximumFlow generates a weird result

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 12.1**

---

Try the following program:

```
FindMaximumFlow[
  Graph[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {d <-> a, b <-> a, a <-> c, d <-> f, 
    f <-> c}, VertexCapacity -> {5, 10, 7, 11, 8, 12}], {d, b}, {c, 
   a}]
```

You may find that it gives you a "seemingly proper" result, but does it?

Try to run this program several times, you'll find that it gives different results! Furthermore, if you can draw out this graph and calculate this manually, you can find the real result should be 12.

It seems that this is not a single case, after changing this code in several ways, I can still find similar problem:

```
Table[FindMaximumFlow[
  Graph[{a, b, c, d, f}, {d <-> a, b <-> a, a <-> c, d <-> f, 
    f <-> c}, VertexCapacity -> {5, 10, 7, 11, 12}], {d, b}, {c}], 10]

Table[FindMaximumFlow[
  Graph[{a, b, c, d, f}, {d <-> a, b <-> a, a <-> c, d <-> f, 
    f <-> c}, VertexCapacity -> {5, 10, 7, 11, 12}], {d, b}, {c}], 10]
```

Did I do anything wrong dealing with this case or it's just a bug?

---

My system information:

Mathematica 10.2,10.3,10.4,10.4.1(This problem exists in all these versions)

CPU: i7-4800mq, i7-6560U

RAM: 8G

Comment: Well, I certainly get different results too. 1-3 on Debian.

Comment: d-b isn't a vertex though?

Comment: Both d and b are vertices. Check usage 3 of FindMaximumFlow at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximumFlow.html?q=FindMaximumFlow

Comment: You're right, it does seem like reversing and putting `{c, a}, {d, b}` actually gives 3 as a consistent answer.

Comment: Nope, try more! It will give out 1,2,3,5,12 while only the last one is correct, sarcastically, the final one occurs the rarest......

Comment: Can I add a 'bugs' tag now?

Comment: I get only `3` as answer, even with `Table` $100$ iterations. But yes, it's certainly a bug, I get weird stuff with other graphs too when VertexCapacity is involved.

Comment: Confirmed in version 10.0.  Version 9.0.1 returns 22 every time.  Is this the expected result?

Comment: No no no, try running it multiple times instead of Table. Sometimes Table generate even more weird results, e.g. Reapeatingly generate 3,2,2 and eventually form a table like {3,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2}

Comment: @Szabolcs It should be 12 if you 'calculate' with your head...... Are you sure it's 22 instead of 12?

Comment: Given this bug, I will consider [adding this functionality to IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues/26) eventually.

Comment: Yes, v9 gives 22.

Comment: How is that possible? Total vertex capacity of vertex a and c are only 12......

Comment: "How is that possible?"  <- Maybe there's a different bug in v9?  Sorry, I am not familiar enough with the topic, and didn't have time to look it up yet.  So I cannot calculate it by hand. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b6mSn.png).

Comment: @Szabolcs Considering I get something different too, it seems like this bug is highly variable.

Comment: Can somebody with access to multiple versions please add the customary header?

Comment: @J.M. OK, added.  I didn't want to add it at first because it wasn't clear if 9.0 was OK, or if not, whether 9.0 had a different problem.

Comment: Have you already reported this to Wolfram support?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot...... I'm currently not a user of proper version of Mathematica...... I use it mainly at school now.

Comment: I reported the problem a long time ago to Wolfram support and was told it had been passed on to the technical team. I was disappointed to see that the problem still persists even in the newest version of Mathematica (v11 Mac OS X latest version) despite the long standing bug.